# Can't implement firebase dependencies on my android app

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, dependencies

i'm developing an Android Studio App and trying to create a user register activity. I already added firebase into the project but when i try to add the firebase database dependencies, the app crashes instantly and not a single error is reported. However, when i remove the 3 implements from the build gradle, it runs correctly. Here i leave both build gradle codes. Thanks.

**Build gradle project:**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Build gradle app (this works properly):**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.jota02"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    //new implements
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0-beta01'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.0.1')
}
```

**Build gradle app (this crashes):**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.jota02"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    //new implements
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0-beta01'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.0.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.0'
}
```

**SOLVED**

The problem just was that i was running an old Android Studio version. I updated Android Studio and checked the gradle versions and now it's all working properly, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you use firebase-bom dependency, you no need to mention version for firebase-database and other firebase library.

firebase-bom will choose right version for you or if you want particular version of firebase remove firebase-bom.so add dependency like below

```
 // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.0.1')

   
    // When using the BoM, you don't specify versions in Firebase library dependencies
     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core'
     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'
```